# Javascript Regex: replacing second set of square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
"something[something][0][]"
```

What I need to do is replace the `[0]` with another number. This is what I've attempted:

```
var name = nameVar.replace(/[^\[\]]+(?=\]\[[^\]]+\]$)/, "999");
```

Any help on the regex expression ?

Comment: Why not just match `\]\[(\d+)\]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a capturing group for first `[...]`:

```
var re = /(\[[^\]]*\])\[[^\]]*\]/; 
var str = 'something[something][0][]';

var result = str.replace(re, '$1[999]');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rO4jD0/5)

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var nameVar = "something[something][0][]"; 
    var name = nameVar.replace(/([^[]+\[[^\]]+\])(\[[^\]]+\])/, '$1[999]');
    alert(name);
}
myFunction()
```